# While Integrating Apple iAd Framework getting Error this error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, iad

I am integrated Apple iAd framework and I am getting this Error.Please Help me on this.

Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. Loading throttled" UserInfo=0x6b57cf0 {ADInternalErrorCode=2, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Loading throttled}

Answer (score 0):

You've created too many banner ads simultaneously or have asked for a lot of ads in rapid succession. Reduce the number of ads you're trying to display and/or slow down your requests for new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the only error you get, or do you get other ones?  Does it work sometime and not others?

The iAd test server tends to return a lot of errors, so that you can test your code for hiding and unhiding the banners and so on.  If it works sometime and not others, then it should be fine - but like @myztikjenz says, you should check the rate/number that you are issuing requests and re-read the documentation to make sure you are issuing your requests correctly.